# Getting All groups that belong to user

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I have HABTM for Users and Groups. I want to show in a Group view - all the Groups that belong to a User. Or to put it differently - all the Groups that have the User.

I am getting tangled in the MVC and am not able to figure it out. Here are my two models:
class Course extends AppModel

```
  public $name = 'Course';
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User' =>
            array(
                'unique' => false
            )
            );
```

And...

```
 public $name = 'User';
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Course' =>
            array(
                'unique' => true
            )
            );
```

The table name in the database is `courses_users` - this table houses group ids and user ids.

Should be simple enough but I'm new to CakePHP so I'd love some help. Thank you!

Comment: I guess the "Cake" way would be to use  Containables - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html. My recommendation would be instead to manually use joins in your `find()` -  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables . The reason is this: say you are looking for all Users in Group X. If you use Containable, it will return ALL Users, and if they aren't in Group X their Group array() will be empty. If they are in Group X, it will be populated with Group X data. Usually not what you want.

Comment: @iso27002 - thanks for this it's very helpful. But I think I have a disconnect in understanding. How am I supposed to use the "connecting table" courses_users to perform the find? The example in the link you sent shows me how to get all of the info about the Groups. But what about finding all of the groups that are associated with the current Auth->User->id?

Comment: If you are using the format you posted above for your `$hasAndBelongsToMany` declaration you need to ensure you follow proper Cake naming conventions so Cake has no issues automatically looking up data. See @Kai's answer for further information.

Comment: Thanks, @iso27002 - Kai's answer was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP has recursive set to 1 by default, which means that assuming you have not changed the recursive setting, it will automatically fetch all associated courses when you call find on a user, assuming you set up the HABTM relationship when doing the find.  Therefore, all you have to do is:

```
$this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
```

In your User model, I don't think it's strictly necessary, but I like to specify the join table and such on HABTM relationships:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Course' =>
        array(
            'unique' => true,
            'dependent' => false,
            'joinTable' => 'courses_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'course_id',
        )
    );
```

Keep in mind that in HABTM relationships, you don't ever really touch the joinTable beyond specifying which table to use as the joinTable when setting up the relationship.  CakePHP will automatically do the rest of the work.

Comment: Thanks @Kai - this is great! But is there an error in the find you put there? There's no mention of courses.

Comment: Nope, as I said, as long as the relationship is set up and recursive is set to 1 or higher, it should automatically get courses with users.  If recursive is set lower than 1, you can however use contain: `$this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id => $this->Auth->user('id')), 'contain' => 'Course'));`

Comment: I figured it out after asking - thanks so much, Kai - this was perfect!

Comment: as a follow up question, do you know how I'd find the Omega of this? Meaning, all courses where the user is not registered?

Comment: That you'll have to make your own join statement I think, something like `$this->Course->find('all', array('joins' => array('table' => 'courses_users', 'alias' => 'CoursesUser', 'type' => 'left', 'conditions' => array('Course.id = CoursesUser.course_id', 'CoursesUser.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));`  I'm not too certain I wrote out that join logic correctly though.